# run 2 identical javascripts on the same page

Tags: javascript

This is a general question. I have a javascript i want to use twice on the same page. It is obvious that whenever i interact with one of them - it will change the other one. I know that renaming method names within them will solve this, but i don't have access to it.
Is there a way to let them both work without collision between the 2 of them?

I thought of wraping each of them inside a javascript with other name, but i am stuck here. 
Any ideas?

Comment: There are too few details on what you want to achieve, please provide some code samples explaining how you want to run this JS twice. Is it via a script tag with src attribute ?

Comment: Yes, with script tag and src attribute conataining url.

Comment: Sounds like you are misusing global variables to me, post some codes please.

Comment: The script contains a few buttons to navigate, and whenever i navigate from one of them - it navigates to all of them, off course.

Comment: I should make clear that i only have the url for the JS, i don't have the js itself...

Comment: Is it possible to see your code and the url?

Answer (score 0):

This is a design problem.

The best way to tackle this is to design the code in the object orientated way, with JS classes (I know a lot of people will tell me that JS has no classes, but it does for all intents and purposes).

For example:

```
// Define the class
function myobject() {

  // Variables belonging to this class
  this.value1 = 0;
  this.value2 = 0;
  this.total = 0;

  // A function within this class
  this.addNumbers = function(){
      this.total = this.value1 + this.value2;
  }
}

// Create two instances of the class
var mything = new myobject();
var mything2 = new myobject();

// Set variables within the instances
mything.value1 = 5;
mything2.value1 = 10;

// Run the function
mything.addNumbers();
mything2.addNumbers();

// Show the result
alert(mything.total);
alert(mything2.total);
```

You now have two instances of myobject which will not conflict with each other.  This class can also have functions inside of it.

So in your case, it might be worth wrapping the JS you have inside a class, then creating instances of that class.

Comment: Could work. @asaf: if you have no access to the script, can't you make a local copy of it and then adjust and load that?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.scripts[Name - or - index].method()
```

OR
Load in different documents. i.e., load second script in iframe document and use it.